# What's the meaning of logistic regression dataset labels?

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm

I've learned the Logistic Regression for some days, and i think the logistic regression's dataset's labels needs to be 1 or 0, is it right ?

But when i lookup the [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/regression.html#bodyfat) library's [regression dataset](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/regression/abalone), i see the label values are continues number(e.g. 1.0086,1.0089 ...), did i miss something ?

Note that the libSVM library could be used for regression problem.

Thanks so much !

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to its name, logistic regression is a classification algorithm and it outputs class probability conditioned on the data point. Therefore the training set labels need to be either 0 or 1. For the dataset you mentioned, logistic regression is not a suitable algorithm.

SVM is a classification algorithm and it uses the input labels -1 or 1. It is not a probabilistic algorithm and it doesn't output class probabilities. It also can be adapted to regression.

Comment: Do you mean the dataset could not used for regression ? But its type called "regression", check it out here:http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/

Comment: You can use the dataset for regression - as you say, this is what it's for. But you can't apply logistic regression to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 3rd party library or programming this yourself? Generally the labels are used as ground truth so you can see how effective your approach was.

For example if your algo is trying to predict what a particular instance is it might output -1, the ground truth label will be +1 which means you did not successfully classify that particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that "regression" is a general term. To say someone will perform regression analysis doesn't necessarily tell you what algorithm they will be using, nor all of the nature of the data sets. All it really tells you is that you have a set of samples with features which you want to use to predict a single outcome value (a model for conditional probability).

One major difference between logistic regression and linear regression is that the former is usually trained on categorical, binary-labeled sample sets; while the latter is trained on real-labeled (ℝ) sample sets.

Any time your labels are real valued, it means you're probably going to use *linear regression* or similar, or else convert those real valued labels to categorical labels (e.g. via thresholds or bins) if you want to in fact use *logistic regression*. There is potentially a big difference in the quality and interpretation of your results though, if you try to convert from one such problem setup to another.

See also [Regression Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).